# Sharing a gorilla/mux router across packages

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm having some issues with implementing a slight MVC design with gorilla/mux.

The layout of the modules is as follows:

```
main.go
-- controllers
---- base.controller.go
---- example.controller.go
-- models
---- base.model.go
---- example.controller.go
```

All the files in `controllers` is in the `controllers` package, same with `models` and then the `main.go` is the `main` package.

Currently I'm just trying to get the `Base Controller` to be able to be shared with the `main package` which is working, although it's throwing some errors when trying to implement routes. The build is not throwing any errors, but the routes are not available. If I implement the `Walk` function in the Gorilla/Mux documentation to print out all the registered routes for the `mux.Router` then it gives me this error:

> &{%!!(MISSING)s(*mux.Router=&{  [0xc4200901b0] map[] true
>   false false false}) %!!(MISSING)s(http.HandlerFunc=0xc8df0)
>   [%!!(MISSING)s(*mux.routeRegexp=&{/ false false true false
>   0xc420095360 / [] []})] %!!(MISSING)s(*mux.routeRegexpGroup=&{
>   0xc420016240 []}) %!!(MISSING)s(bool=true) %!!(MISSING)s(bool=false)
>   %!!(MISSING)s(bool=false)  %!!(MISSING)s(bool=false)  
>   %!!(MISSING)s(mux.BuildVarsFunc=)}

The reasoning for the global `var V1Router *mux.Router` is firstly to access it in the `main package` and also to create subrouters in the other controllers.

I am fairly new to `Go`, but I'm trying my best to learn the best practices! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example code below:

`base.controllers.go`

```
package controllers

import (
        "fmt"
        "bytes"
        "net/http"
        "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var V1Router *mux.Router

func init () {
    V1Router = mux.NewRouter()
    V1Router.StrictSlash(true)
    V1Router.HandleFunc("/", BaseHandler)    
}

// Base route to access the API Documentation.
func BaseHandler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, Gophers!")
}
```

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "github.com/projectrepo/project/models"
    "github.com/projectrepo/project/controllers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main () {
    http.Handle("/v1", controllers.V1Router)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Serving error.")
    }
}
```

In response to the comments, I tried this solution with the same result:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "github.com/projectrepo/project/models"
    "github.com/projectrepo/project/controllers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main () {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Handle("/v1", controllers.V1Router)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Serving error.")
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not mix the standard mux (`http.DefaultServerMux`) and `gorilla/mux`. You should pass `gorilla router` as the second argument of `http.ListenAndServe` if you wan't to replace the standard one. How is your controller's paths will look like?

Comment: @putu What I did now was added a default `r := mux.NewRouter()` in the `main package` and handled `/v1/` as the `controllers.V1Router()` and I'm getting a nil pointer error. I did add `r` to replace the `nil` in `ListenAndServe`.

Comment: @putu Okay, that was my mistake - I had an error while debugging. Fixing everything the way it was I get the same error.

Comment: My first comment may be not 100% correct. You can mix it, *but*  it only works if you register it through `http.Handle("/", controllers.V1Router)` or passing it as second argument of `http.ListenAndServe`. The sub-router for `/v1` must be created using [`Route.Subrouter`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.Subrouter), e.g. `v1 := V1Router.PathPrefix("/v1").Subrouter()`, then register base controller to `v1`.

Comment: @putu, the first part of your comment - is that not the same solution as my first attempt?

Comment: No, it's not. I try to explained it in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gorilla `mux.Router` is supposed to be used to create mapping between a set of predefined rules (e.g. host, path, protocol, scheme, etc...) and it's handler (`http.Handler` or `http.HandlerFunc`). Gorilla mux can be used to replace standard server mux. If you combine `gorilla/mux` with built in http server mux as your original question, i.e.

```
func main () {
    http.Handle("/v1", controllers.V1Router)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Serving error.")
    }
}
```

what actually happen when a client access `/v1` is `controllers.V1Router` will be called with request path `/v1` passed to `V1Router1`. In the `controllers.V1Router`, you defined that `/` will be handled by `BaseHandler`. However, since incoming request path is `/v1`, it won't match to your routing table. If you want to define sub routing, you can do as follows (this is what I mean in first comment):

```
func main () {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    v1 := r.PathPrefix("/v1").Subrouter()
    controllers.RegisterHandlers(v1)

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Serving error.")
    }
}
```

Then in the controllers (`base.controllers.go`) define

```
//Register handlers and it's sub router
func RegisterHandlers(r *mux.Router) {
    //base handler, i.e. /v1
    r.StrictSlash(true)
    r.HandleFunc("/", BaseHandler)

    //example sub-router, i.e. /v1/example
    ex := r.PathPrefix("/example").Subrouter()
    ex.HandleFunc("/", ExampleHandler)

    //other handlers...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a great explanation. I've edited my structure and it's working great. :)